# How to pass text from textarea to reflect or show in another page, without losing the formatting?

Tags: javascript, php

I am making an application using javascript (no JQuery) and php.  I have a textarea form -which applies - space formatting. But when I send the values from this textarea to another page using PHP post command ..the spacing is gone. How can I reflect the content of the textarea along with spacing?

Comment: Use `nl2br` inside PHP, spacing are still there but they cannot be shown in HTML in the same way as for `textarea`

Comment: How do I get the new lines but without showing <br /> tag , as the text gets reflected.

Comment: something like: `str_replace('<br />', "\r\n", $field)`

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy..

use 'n2blr` function.

```
The nl2br() function inserts HTML line breaks (<br> or <br />) in front of each newline (\n) in a string.
```

See [demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/pcbx-p6yd) for understand it well

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I am wondering if other formats can be preserved as well - if i use a text editor - such as CK editor - instead of a text area form.

Comment: CK editor is formatted <textarea> and makes it text editor so i think this function works there also.